# AWS step function calling gateway - how to pass username/password to REST API being called

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have created a step function that calls a lambda through AWS Gateway using API Gateway Invoke - works fine.  Now I want to create a new step function that will call an external REST API through the AWS Gateway.

What I am having trouble is how do I define the authentication parameters?  In Insomnia or Postman it would be Basic Auth where you define username and password.

I just can't seem to find where in the invoke json I define the authentication parameters that get passed to the REST API.

I have the headers, method, query parameters, etc.  How do I define the auth parameters?  For this am I required to have a lambda and cannot go straight to the API from the gateway?

```
      "Parameters": {
        "ApiEndpoint": "04azkjak9k.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
        "Method": "GET",
        "Headers": {
          "key": [
            "value"
          ]
        },
        "Stage": "<<<stage value>>>",
        "Path": "<<<path value>>>",
        "QueryParameters": {
          "key": [
            "value"
          ]
        },
```

I saw reference to http integration to allow API Gateway to reach an external URL but I am reaching out to an external API not under my control.  I feel like I am totally missing obvious stuff.